# Row added by script not deleting

Tags: jquery

i have used a script there i am adding a row on click of a class. i have added a close span inside the added row. but when i try make a onlick event for the close class to close the added row, it does not work.
Here is the script for adding row and the close class added to it:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('table.listtable td input.selectseat').one('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color','#faf5d5');
        $(this).parent().parent().after('<tr class="seating"><td colspan="6"><span class="closeseats"></span></td></tr>');
        $('tr.seating').css('background-color','#faf5d5');
    });
}); 


</script>
```

this script is adding the row i needed, with the close span also added. till now its fine. now i  want that on click of  span woth the class of "closeseats", the row that was added should be deleted. 
ALSO, REMEBER THAT THIS IS A LIST. SO I HAVE LOT OF BUTTONS WITH THE SAME CLASS "selectseat". SO ON CLICKING OF SPAN WITH CLASS "closeseats", IT SHOULD ONLY CLOSE THE RELATING TR.SEATING.
THE HTML OF THE TABLE IS LIKE THIS:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="listtable">
  <tr class="firstone">
<th align="left" valign="top">Bus Type</th>    
<th align="left" valign="top">Departure</th>
    <th align="left" valign="top">Duration</th>
    <th align="left" valign="top">Arrival</th>
    <th align="left" valign="top">Seats</th>
    <th align="left" valign="top">Fare</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle">Volvo, A/C, Seater</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><img src="img/morning.png" /> <br />
9:00 PM</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">3h</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><img src="img/evening.png" /> <br />
7:00 PM</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">4</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" class="amount">Rs. 460 <br /><br />
<input type="submit" class="selectseat" value="Select Seats" /><span class="ttip" title='this one <br> that one'><img src="img/plus.png" alt="plus"/></span></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle">Volvo, A/C, Seater</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><img src="img/morning.png" /> <br />
9:00 PM</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">3h</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><img src="img/evening.png" /> <br />
7:00 PM</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">4</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" class="amount">Rs. 460<br /><br />
<input type="submit" class="selectseat" value="Select Seats" /><span class="ttip" title="this one"><img src="img/plus.png" alt="plus"/></span></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle">Volvo, A/C, Seater</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><img src="img/morning.png" /> <br />
9:00 PM</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">3h</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><img src="img/evening.png" /> <br />
7:00 PM</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">4</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" class="amount">Rs. 460<br /><br />
<input type="submit" class="selectseat" value="Select Seats" /><span class="ttip" title="this one"><img src="img/plus.png" alt="plus"/></span></td>

</tr>



</table>
```

please help.

Comment: Instead of `$(this).parent().parent()` you could use `$(this).closest('tr')`.

Comment: use `$(this).closest('tr').css(` instead of `$(this).parent().parent().css(`

Comment: @DipeshParmar What a sync !

Answer (score 0):

you have to use event delegation since you have to deal with dynamic elements, [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/#one-events-selector-data-handlereventObject) supports a event delegation

```
$(function() {
    $('table.listtable').one('click', '.closeseats', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr.seating').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks all for answering, but that didnot answer my question i guess. i wanted that the class "closeseats" ion clicking should delete the tr.seating which was created dynamically

Comment: i used your script but replaced .one with .on and its working fine. BUT ONE PROBLEM IS THERE... once i close the tr.seating class with onclick of .closeseats, i cannot reproduce the tr.seating on that same button, which i want to.i mean, once closed, the same tr.seating cannot be reproduced by clicking on ".selectseat" class